# CSS cubes, trouble aligning to grid

Tags: css, 3d, transform

So my goal is to have these cubes on a grid and have them line up, draggable and snappable.  I got the cubes working well based on [this example](http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/examples/cube-02-show-sides.html), but I'm not fully comprehending some of the mechanics and as such am having some problems.

1. The cube starts out larger than it is after it rotates.  To see this, simply click "1" which applies the "show-front" class, while you're still on the front face.  It will immediately shrink.  **fixed**
2. The cube axis is not centered, so when it rotates it ends up at different xy coordinates.
3. In the CSS I'm setting the size to 200x200 (or any factor of 25) but due to the Z transform it's not exactly right.  **This one is mostly fixed, see update at bottom.**

How can I fix these three things?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/scottbeeson/phJpS/

Here is the CSS which is the important part:

```
    .itemView {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      /*position: relative;*/
      /*margin: 0 auto 40px;*/
      /*border: 1px solid #CCC;*/
      -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
         -moz-perspective: 1000px;
           -o-perspective: 1000px;
              perspective: 1000px;
        -webkit-margin-start: 0 !important;
        -webkit-margin-before: 0 !important;
        -webkit-margin-end: 0 !important;
        -webkit-margin-after: 0 !important;
    }

    .cube {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
         -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
           -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
              transform-style: preserve-3d;
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
         -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
           -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
              transition: transform 1s;
    }

    .cube figure {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      width: 196px;
      height: 196px;
      border: 2px solid black;
      color: white;
    }

    .cube.panels-backface-invisible figure {
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
         -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
           -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
              backface-visibility: hidden;
    }

    .cube .front  {     
        background-color: #555;
        border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    }
    .cube .back   {
        background-color: #555;
        border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    }
    .cube .right  { 
        background-color: #555;
        border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    }
    .cube .left   { 
        background-color: #555;
        border: 1px solid #ccc; 
     }
    .cube .top    {
        background-color: cornflowerblue;
        border: 1px solid #ccc; 
     }
    .cube .bottom { 
        background-color: #555;
        border: 1px solid #ccc; 
     }

    .cube .front  {
      -webkit-transform: translateZ( 99px );
    }
    .cube .back   {
      -webkit-transform: rotateX( -180deg ) translateZ( 99px );
    }
    .cube .right {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(   90deg ) translateZ( 99px );
    }
    .cube .left {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(  -90deg ) translateZ( 99px );
    }
    .cube .top {
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(   90deg ) translateZ( 99px );
    }
    .cube .bottom {
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(  -90deg ) translateZ( 99px );
    }

    .cube.show-front {
      -webkit-transform: translateZ( -99px );
    }
    .cube.show-back {
      -webkit-transform: translateZ( -99px ) rotateX( -180deg );
    }
    .cube.show-right {
      -webkit-transform: translateZ( -99px ) rotateY(  -90deg );
    }
    .cube.show-left {
      -webkit-transform: translateZ( -99px ) rotateY(   90deg );
    }
    .cube.show-top {
      -webkit-transform: translateZ( -99px ) rotateX(  -90deg );
    }
    .cube.show-bottom {
      -webkit-transform: translateZ( -99px ) rotateX(   90deg );
    }

.itemHandle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    cursor: move;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    text-align: left;
    /*border-top-right-radius: 15px;*/
}
```

Also, if anyone feels like these should be separate questions, that's fine.  I just figured they're all part of the same "problem" and it would be easier than posting the same fiddle 3 times.

**update on #1, #3** ([updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scottbeeson/phJpS/3/))

I was able to change transformZ of the front face to 0 and adjust the rest of the transforms to basically make the front face of the cube on the same plane as the "workArea".  This is much better, but the perspective is a little off, as if you're not looking head-on towards the cube.  Not noticeable though unless the faces are translucent. Here is the updated CSS:

```
.cube .front  {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ( 0px );
}
.cube .back   {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX( -180deg ) translateZ( 200px );
}
.cube .right {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(   90deg ) translateZ( 100px ) translateX(100px);
}
.cube .left {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(  -90deg ) translateZ( 100px ) translateX(-100px);
}
.cube .top {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(   90deg ) translateZ( 100px ) translateY(-100px);
}
.cube .bottom {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(  -90deg ) translateZ( 100px ) translateY(100px);
}
```

Comment: I removed all CSS besides Chrome vendor-specific since that's what I'm debugging in.  Too much clutter.

Comment: Added example in my answer, hope it is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The figures are off because of margin and padding.

Try :

```
.cube figure {
     display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 0px solid black;
    color: white;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
```

Added margin and padding = 0

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/phJpS/4/)

I have now changed the whole coordinate system. It is easier if you make the cube center be at 0 0 coordinates. Now all the rotating stuff only needs rotation, and that is much easier to figure out.

If you really wnat the front face to be on the z=0 plane, set an global offset at the base level.

Comment: Looks great! I'll accept as soon as I can get it integrated.  Thanks!

Comment: So there's one problem with that, since the face is using translateZ(100) it's like the whole cube is zoomed in.  Ideally I would like the faces to be level with the plane of the background.  I have moved the whole cube back so that this is true, but now it rotates on a different axis.  Ideas?  Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/scottbeeson/phJpS/5/

Comment: Crap, I just read the end of your post, sorry... let me play with it.

Comment: So I added translateZ( -200px ); to .cube and it starts out correct but when it rotates it "zooms" back in again.

Comment: I'm going to open a new question since you got me to 95% and this one is so convoluted now.